# React-Redux unable to fetch data from firebase react native

Tags: firebase, react-native, react-redux

I have created a database in firebase the schema is below:

[image]

Now All I have been trying to do is just have it show up when I do a console log but nothing shows up.

Below is the code for my JobsActions.js

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
import {
  JOBS_FETCH_SUCCESS
} from './types';

export const jobsFetch = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    firebase.database().ref('/jobs')
      .on('value', snapshot => {
        dispatch({ type: JOBS_FETCH_SUCCESS, payload: snapshot.val() });
      });
  };
};
```

This is my reducer:

```
import {
    JOBS_FETCH_SUCCESS
  } from '../actions/types';

  const INITIAL_STATE = {
     // jobs: 'RCCA'
  };

  export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
     switch (action.type) {
       case JOBS_FETCH_SUCCESS:
         console.log(action);
         return state;
         //return action.payload;
       default:
        return state;
  }
};
```

This is the JobsList

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { jobsFetch } from '../actions';


class JobsList extends Component {

   componentWillMount() {
     this.props.jobsFetch();
   }

  render() {
    return (

    <View style={{ paddingTop: 20 }}>
        <Text>Hello</Text>
    </View>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(null, { jobsFetch })(JobsList);
```

I have authentication using firebase and its not a connection to firebase thats an issue, From what I see, it seems like maybe the ref path is wrong in the Actions file?

Answer (score 0):

You main problem here is not with Firebase actually, since I believe everything else is allright, but with React-Redux.

When you are connecting a component to the store, the connect function recieves two functions. The first one (usually called `mapStateToProps`) recieves the state and returns an object that will be added to the props. In this case, you are not using it, so passing `null` is a valid decision.

The second one (usually called `mapDispatchToProps`) receives the dispatch as a parameter and should return an object with the functions that will be inserted to the props that can be used to dispatch new actions. In this case, you are just passing an object as the second parameter of the connect `{ jobsFetch }`.

When you do `this.props.jobsFetch();` you are actually returning the function that receives the dispatch, so nothing is actually executed.

Your `mapDispatchToProps` should be something similar to this

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    jobsFetch : () => dispatch(jobsFetch())
  }
}

export default connect(
  null,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(JobsList)
```

Here, I'm assuming that you are in fact using [Redux thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) since you are returning a function that receives the dispatch as a parameter in your actions.

As you may see, we first call the `jobsFetch()` in order to get the function that receives the reducer, and then we dispatch it.

Let me know if this does not work! There may be something else that is not correct, but this is something that should be addressed. Hope it helps!